# Flash text disappearing when using draw method

Tags: ios, flash, air

Working on an AIR iOS app and noticed a strange thing.

In my app I have a navigation panel that displays over the main content-holding Sprite. Having this panel display was causing the app to crash on iPad1 (guessing too much memory). So I added a function to basically draw the content-holder Sprite (via BitmapData draw function) into a Sprite above it, and turn the content-holder visibility off. Basically, taking a screenshot.

However, I'm seeing on 2 different iPads now that any dynamically added text in the content-holder isn't being drawn. Sometimes, the first time it does, but not after.

One thing noticed is that turning off the cacheAsBitmap property of the text fields fixes the problem. Unfortunately, that is not an option as the app is very text heavy and the performance is noticeably slower if the dynamically generated text isn't bitmapped.

Any ideas on what may be going on?

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cacheAsBitmap on the dynamic text fields was the problem. By turning that off temporarily, taking the screenshot and then turning back on when done with screenshot, I was able to work around the issue.

Not sure if it's an AIR/iOS issue or maybe a lack of memory?

FYI, in case somebody sees similar problem. Hope that helps.